# VB6 appendChunk JAVA string

Tags: java, string, jpa, vb6

before ask here I searched a lot without finding a solution.
I've a legacy VB6 application that store PDF inside SQL Database in a VARBINARY(MAX) columns.
The space used by the columns is the double of the PDF file. I've read that is due to Widechar.
Now I need to read this data stored in DB from JAVA. I use JPA to access database.
I receive a byte[] that I save to file. The file has the size of the database column and it fails to open.
I've tried to convert with StandardCharset.UTF16 or UTF16LE but it still fails. The only thing that I see is that with UTF16LE it has the right size, it is opened from PDF reader, it has the right number of pages but the pages are totally white.
I hope that someone has a solution for me.

My VB6 code:

```
Public Function GetrdoColumnWithGetChunk_BYTE(rdoCol As rdoColumn, vValue() As Byte, Optional ChunkSize As Long = 100 * 1024!)

Dim FileLen As Long
Dim Chunks As Long
Dim iChunk As Long
Dim Fragment As Long
Dim Chunk() As Byte
Dim NextIdxReferto As Long
Dim iByte As Long

On Error GoTo GetrdoColumnWithGetChunk_BYTE_Error

If ChunkSize <= 0 Then ChunkSize = 100 * 1024!

FileLen = rdoCol.ColumnSize
Chunks = FileLen \ ChunkSize
Fragment = FileLen Mod ChunkSize

ReDim vValue(0 To 0)

If Fragment <> 0 Then
    Chunk() = rdoCol.GetChunk(Fragment)
    ReDim vValue(0 To UBound(Chunk))
    For iByte = LBound(Chunk) To UBound(Chunk)
        vValue(iByte) = Chunk(iByte)
    Next iByte
    NextIdxReferto = UBound(vValue) + 1
Else
    NextIdxReferto = 0
End If
For iChunk = 1 To Chunks
    Chunk() = rdoCol.GetChunk(ChunkSize)
    ReDim Preserve vValue(0 To NextIdxReferto + UBound(Chunk))
    For iByte = LBound(Chunk) To UBound(Chunk)
        vValue(NextIdxReferto + iByte) = Chunk(iByte)
    Next iByte
    NextIdxReferto = UBound(vValue) + 1
Next iChunk

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

GetrdoColumnWithGetChunk_BYTE_Error:

    If Err.Number = 32755 Then Exit Function
    Call WriteOnLogEx(MY_CFG.LOG_ERROR, App.Title & " > Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure GetrdoColumnWithGetChunk_BYTE of Modulo di classe Functions", 0, 0)
    Resume Next


End Function
```

Inside Java my code is:

```
Charset originCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE;

ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdf);
// decode UTF_16LE
CharBuffer data = originCharset.decode(inputBuffer);
// encode UTF_8
ByteBuffer outputBuffer = destinationCharset.encode(data);
byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();

return outputData;
```

This produce a PDF that could be open with PDF reader but it has all the page blank.

Mirko

Comment: Sounds like you did a conversion from ANSI to Unicode somewhere along the line.  Perhaps implicitly by reading the original data into a String?  Don't use String variables for binary data, use Byte arrays.  BTW: There are SQL databases and NoSQL databases of many kinds, but I think what you are trying to say is that you have a SQL Server database.

Comment: Hello, I use a Microsoft SQL database.

Comment: Hallo, is there anyone who can give me an help? thanks in advance